# Hii all!! I am new to development.Can't get why the following code prints "message": "Something Went Wrong" when sending POST request using postman

Tags: reactjs, api, mongoose, mongoose-schema

router.post('/signup',(req,res) => {

```
//check if already Exist

User.findOne({email : req.body.email})
.exec((error,user) =>{
     
    if(user)return res.status(400).json({
        message:'User Already Registered'
    });
    
    const {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        password
    } = req.body; 

    const _user = new User({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        password,
        username:Math.random().toString()
    });

    _user.save((error,data) => {
        
        if(error)return res.status(400).json({
          message:'Something Went Wrong'
        });

        if(data){
          return res.status(201).json({
              user:data
            });
        }
        

    });

});
```

});

---

User Schema is as follows

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

firstName : {
    type:String,
    required:true,
    trim:true,
    min:3,
    max:20
},
lastName : {
    type:String,
    required:true,
    trim:true,
    min:3,
    max:20
},
userName:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    trim:true,
    unique:true,
    index:true,
    lowercase:true
},
email:{

    type:String,
    required:true,
    trim:true,
    unique:true,
    lowercase:true
},
hash_password:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
},
role:{
    type:String,
    enum:['user','admin'],
    default:'user'
},
contactNumber:{
    type:String
},
profilePicture:{ 
   type:String
}
```

},{timestamps:true});

=========================================================================
Error is:
Error: User validation failed: userName: Path `userName` is required., firstName: Path `firstName` is required., lastName: Path `lastName` is required.
at ValidationError.

==========================================================================

Comment: Not exactly sure why either, but a if you haven't already, I would suggest logging the error using `console.log(error)` to see what is happening. Maybe once you see what the error is, you can post it here for a little more context :) GL

Comment: @JesseSainz Thanks for quick response.  "The error is  Error: User validation failed: userName: Path `userName` is required., firstName: Path `firstName` is required., lastName: Path `lastName` is required. at ValidationError."

Comment: One issue is that `userName` is required, but you are setting `username` when you create the user. For `firstName` and `lastName` are you sure those are on the `req.body`? I recommend logging out the `req.body` to verify.

Comment: @AdamExchange Thanks a lot!! Solved.You pointed it right. Silly typing mistake I did :(